# Structural induction - Unsure of which direction to go.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, recursion

So I'm supposed to use the recursive definition of #c(s) -- the number of occurrences of the character c in A in a string s. I'm tasked with proving the lemma:

## c(s * t) = #c(s) + #c(t).

I was also given the two definitions:
[definitions][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyfAy.jpg

So far I have my basis down, by setting both s & t to the empty string and showing that the lemma holds for this case.

However, for my constructor case, I am unsure of how to show equivalence for both sides. I was going to use the constructor case of definition 3.2 in the image, but I get stuck trying to work out the right side. Any suggestions?

p.s. - i dont have 10 rep yet, so i can't post inline pics. sorry

Comment: For any s, prove by induction on the length t with base case of empty string t.

Comment: How does proving on the length of t help me? Sorry, if that's a terrible question, I'm a little lost.

Answer (score 1):

c(s.nul) = c(s) + c(nul), . concatenation
c(s.x) = c(s) + c(x), x single letter

c(s.t.x) = c(s.t) + c(x) = c(s) + c(t) + c(x) = c(s) + c(t.x)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess I was having trouble with the expansion portion. How you went from c(s.t) + c(x) to c(s) + c(t) + c(x). Like which definition?

Comment: @aBitwise.  That is the induction step.